# htaccess rewrite directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I moved my website from the /v1/etc... directory to the /v2/etc... directory and would like to make a permanent redirect in htaccess. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^v1(/.*)?$ /v2$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html):

```
Redirect permanent /v1 /v2
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /v1/(.\*) /v2/(.\*) [R=301,L]
```

in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: what a moron, it put .* in the redirected value instead of $1 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch permanent /v1/(.*) /v2/$1
```