# Apache redirect localhost to localhost/abc/def/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, yii

I want to map "localhost/" to "localhost/abc/def/" in apache. How should I edit .htaccess to achieve this?

Comment: See here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472960/htaccess-rewrite-directory>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect just this one URL, use this simple [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /abc/def/ [R,L]
```

If you want to move the whole site instead, you can use [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

```
Redirect / /abc/def/
```