# Redirect localhost to project folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a project in xampp/htdocs/bos.
Whenever I hit http://localhost, I need to land directly to xampp/htdocs/bos 
and URL displaying in browser should be http://localhost only, throughout the application.

I have followed similar questions asked already but no luck.

When i create virtual host in file like

DocumentRoot C:/xampplite/htdocs/bos/
    ServerName hosted_ip_here

and accessing the same ip from other location within MAN
It will create URL localhost/bos.
I only need hosted_ip_here to be displayed in the URL and not "bos"
i.e. Application Name

[Apache redirect localhost to localhost/abc/def/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455868/apache-redirect-localhost-to-localhost-abc-def)

[setup apache virtualhost (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658173/setup-apache-virtualhost-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setup apache virtualhost (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658173/setup-apache-virtualhost-windows)

Comment: I have hosted that application on windows server.When i put ip of the server i need direct access of application without application name anywhere in the MAN

Answer (score 0):

you can do one you must have a index.php file in htdocs you can change header location over there

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the php ini file 'Dir' to and specify the address