# add .htm prefix to extensionless URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I have a directory say `dir1` in my site.

No,w I want all the pages without extension in this directory to redirect to page with `.htm` extension. But they should keep working. i.e. There should no 404 error.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, it's related to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472960/htaccess-rewrite-directory)

Comment: @user2062950 No, this is completely different

Comment: So, `/dir/file1` and `/dir/file2` should redirect to `/dir/file1.htm` and `/dir/file2.htm` respectively? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, but the question you linked to is about different directories

Comment: Okay, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605184/how-to-redirect-all-my-urls-with-no-extension-to-end-with-php) then. The basic idea is `.htaccess` and `mod-rewrite` are used.

Comment: @user2062950 Oops! Little different again. The hosted pages are  extension less in my case