# How To Write .htaccess Vanity URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, vanity-url

I have written a .htaccess vanity url to redirect to users clans (or groups as most of you's may call the functionality) so instead of domain.com/groups/clan.php?id=something I have it operating as domain.com/something

Now what I want is with the posts instead of domain.com/groups/view_update.php?pid=post_id I want domain.com/soomething-group-name/posts/post_id

How can I archive this as I am stumped??

Here's my Code So Far:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Make sure you only match on files/directories that don't actually exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite the first part after the `/` into a `username` parameter

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ groups/index.php?gname=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks Loads :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess rewrite directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472960/htaccess-rewrite-directory)

Comment: not whatI exactly want I want vanity urls

Comment: You need to rewrite the `soomething-group-name` directory to the `groups`, therefore this is what you're in need of.

Comment: could you please show me an example not good with .htaccess

Comment: need it like facebook dan.user.16/posts/7473950853084899